# Is there any method to remove javascript code from an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I want to remove all the javascript code from an HTML document, and leave the actual text. Is there any regex or python script to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

with open("with-scripts.html", "r") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())

for script in soup("script"):
    script.extract()

with open("without-scripts.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regex looking for `'<script'` and `'script>'` and  very well do it.

Edit: As @cHao points out - [Regex's are bad for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454/319403%20here).

Regex might still be useful, at places where you have full control over HTML.

Comment: `<script> document.write('</' + 'script>'); </script>`

Comment: `<script language=javascript>`

Comment: Suffice to say, using regexes for this is brokenness waiting to happen.  (Insert obligatory link to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732454/319403 here.)

Comment: @cHao Thanks a lot. Should have thought about it. Should I delete the answer ?

Comment: If it were my answer, i would -- no single regex of reasonable size is going to suffice for all conceivable possibilities.  But it could be useful on HTML you have full control over (and you can guarantee won't have any corner cases).  Really, it's your call.

Comment: @cHao Yes. very contextual (in terms of having control over HTML).  I would leave the answer here - just in case anyone thinks about it and then gets directed to the better answer through your comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jQuery code to remove:

```
$(javascript).html('')
```

and Firebug to inject your jQuery code into the webpage:

```
>>> var x = window.open(""); 
Window opened 
>>> x 
Window about:blank 
>>> x.document 
Document about:blank 
>>> x.document.write("$(javascript).html('')"); 
Alert popped up
```